# bumblebee does not work with metacity and KWin, but works with compiz

Tags: wine, nvidia-optimus, bumblebee

If I try to launch something with optirun under compiz, it works.

If I try to launch something with optirun under KDE or metacity, it gives me:

```
[  247.384077] [ERROR]Cannot access secondary GPU - error: [XORG] (EE) 

[  247.384117] [ERROR]Aborting because fallback start is disabled.
```

If it matters, I'm trying to launch Portal 2 with wine

I have:
Nvidia GeForce GT540M with optimus
Acer Aspire Timeline X
Intel core i5 and 3000 Integrated Graphics

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with primus, which has different options for different configurations: https://raw.github.com/Bumblebee-Project/Bumblebee/master/doc/RELEASE_NOTES_3_1